# The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

We're testing our open graph tags for `https://www.roadgoat.com` with the [Facebook Share Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing). 
We keep getting the error: `The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id`

We've already tried such mentioned solutions such as:

- Making sure there aren't duplicate entries for any of the tags
- Using the http version of the image instead of https
- Checking each entry to make sure no issues
- Adding og:locale
- Making sure SSL is valid

I've also tested both our JS site and our pre-rendered version of the page `https://www.roadgoat.com?_escaped_fragment_=` and still get the issue in both cases.  It seems to pass on any site I test on besides Facebook's.

I've also checked [See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.roadgoat.com%2F) and I see all the tags, just as expected

Answer (score 1):

From your site:

```
<meta content='{{metadata.description}}' name='description' ng-if='metadata.description'>
<meta content='en_US' property='og:locale'>
<meta content='519642741544020' property='fb:app_id'>
<meta content='{{og_meta.type}}' ng-if='og_meta.type' property='og:type'>
<meta content='{{og_meta.url}}' ng-if='og_meta.url' property='og:url'>
<meta content='{{og_meta.title}}' ng-if='og_meta.title' property='og:title'>
<meta content='{{og_meta.image}}' ng-if='og_meta.image' property='og:image'>
<meta content='{{og_meta.image_width}}' ng-if='og_meta.image_width' property='og:image:width'>
<meta content='{{og_meta.image_height}}' ng-if='og_meta.image_height' property='og:image:height'>
<meta content='{{og_meta.description}}' ng-if='og_meta.description' property='og:description'>
<meta content='RoadGoat' property='og:site_name'>
```

The site is rendering the tags instead of values, there's nothing wrong with Facebook! Some content values like `og:url`, `og:image` are invalid, debugger will throw errors for these.

Comment: But I get the same errors with a page that has pre-rendered all the values.  Try inputting this url and see what I mean:  https://www.roadgoat.com?_escaped_fragment_=

Comment: Also Facebook can render the JS.  Here's exactly what Facebook sees: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.roadgoat.com%2F

Comment: The only difference I could find between your site and social media targeted site is position position of property and content, (they have property first, content next).

Your og: properties are detected as automatic (and they're correct), the site will look as expected on Facebook. If you're close to launch of something, fix warnings later.

Can you change position of property and content?